# Continuously read data from a serial port while loop is running

Tags: mysql, c, while-loop

First, please refer to this block of code:

```
while(1) {
    lt = time(NULL);
    ptr = localtime(&lt);

    int n = read (fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    strftime(str, 100, "%c", ptr);

    int temp = sprintf(tempCommand, "UPDATE roomtemp SET Temperature='%s' WHERE Date='Today'", buf);
    temp = sprintf(dateCommand, "UPDATE roomtemp SET Date='%s' WHERE Type='DisplayTemp'", str);

    printf("%s", buf);
    mysql_query(conn, tempCommand);
    mysql_query(conn, dateCommand);
}
```

The read function is actually reading data coming in from a serial port. It works great, but the problem I am experiencing (I think) is the time it takes for the loop to execute. I have data being sent to the serial port every second. Suppose the data is "22" every second. What this loop does is read in "2222" or sometimes "222222". What I think is happening is that the loop takes too long to iterate, and that causes data to accumulate in the serial buffer. The read statement reads in everything in the buffer, hence giving me repeated values.

Is there any way to get around this? Perhaps at the end of the loop, I can flush the buffer. But I am not certain I know how to do this. Or perhaps there is some way to cut down the code inside the loop in order to reduce the overall time each iteration takes in the first place. My guess is that the MySQL queries are what take the most time anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To start with you should check for errors from `read`, and also properly terminate the received "string".

To continue with your problem, there are a couple of ways to solve this. One it to put either the reading from the serial port or the database updates in a separate thread. Then you can pass "messages" between the the threads. Be careful though, as it seems your database is slow and the message queue might build up. This message-buildup can be averted by having a message queue of size one, which always contain the latest temperature read. Then you only need a single flag that the temperature reading thread sets, and the database updating thread checks and then clears.

Another solution is to modify the protocol used for the communication, so it includes a digit to tell how big the message is.